# iOS UIGestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch - panGesture velocity is 0

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know the velocity of the pan gesture to determine if the gesture is swipe down or swipe up. If the swipe is downwards, then the view should not receive the touch and return the touch to its superview by the hitTest, which will process the touch event, if the touch is upward, then the current view should process the touch event. However, I cannot get the velocity of the touch inside the shouldReceiveTouch method inside the current view(the subview).

Is is because the touch will not actually be processed until it the gestureRcognizerShouldBegin method get called?

If my idea doesn't work, is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14410776/3172726) might help you what you actually want. What you have to do is to use your target function and use **Y** value to get the direction.

I have just shared how that thread helped us.You could try.

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
if ((recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
    (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded))
{
    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];

    if (velocity.y >0)   // panning down
    {
      //Do your thing
    }
    else                // panning up
    {
      //Do your thing
    }
}
}
```